# I can't install windows 64bit on Virtualbox headless

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtualization, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to install Windows2008r2 64bit on a Ubuntu 12.04 64bit host. After created the VM (with `--ostype windows2008_64` I boot up the installation iso but windows says:

```
Attempting to load a 64-bit application, however this cpu is not compatible with 64-bit mode
```

I did `--vtxvpid on` but nothing changes.

### Output requested

```
# uname -i
x86_64
# grep flags /proc/cpuinfo | head -1
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
```

What I have to verify?

Comment: What is the output of `grep flags /proc/cpuinfo | head -1` and `uname -i`?

Comment: Do you have the 64-bit version of VirtualBox, then?

Comment: @Kreker I was looking for the VMX flag which you have. Hrmm...

Comment: yes Michael.  virtualbox-4.1_4.1.18-78361~Ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb

Comment: am I missing something important in the vm creation process?

Answer (score -3):

note that you can't virtualise 64 bits in a virtualised environement, you will have to virtualise in 32 bits, Also make sure that you have virtualization enabled in your bios cpu settings, and that your CPU actually supoprts virtualization

Comment: What exactly are you talking about? Of **course** you can "virtualise 64 bits in a virtualised environement".

Comment: If the server is virtualised you won't be able to. like exemple if you virtualize your esxi server then you wont be able to create 64 bits VM's into it

Comment: With modern (read: post-Nehalem) processors that have the vmx flag, nested 64-bit systems are quite possible.